# como poner una tabla temporal en un cursor?

Tags: sql-server

estoy haciendo un cursor, de hecho, lo tengo con lo básico:

```
DECLARE hor_clases_est CURSOR 
FOR
select clase_nom,
fecha_inic,
fecha_fin,
asignatura,
profesor,
estudiante ,
doc_estudiante from dbo.horarios_clase
ORDER BY fecha_inic 

open hor_clases_est

FETCH NEXT FROM hor_clases_est

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN 

FETCH NEXT FROM hor_clases_est
END
CLOSE hor_clases_est
DEALLOCATE hor_clases_est
```

lo que necesito es crear una tabla temporal de manera que cuando en el cursor se ejecute, me muestre las filas pero eliminándose el anterior registro, quedo atento ante cualquier respuesta o duda en cuanto al planteamiento de mi pregunta

mi objetivo es actualizar la columna `doc_estudiante` ya que está en blanco
lo tengo pensado hacer de manera dinámica declarando `@documento` pero requiero de una tabla tmporal que me permita tomar una fila y después del `fetch`borrar dicha fila y tabla y que se rehaga con cada fila hasta terminar con cada una de estas

Comment: No comprendo lo que necesitas hacer. Sugiero que agregues una pequeña muestra de los datos de entrada y cómo deben quedar estos datos al final.

Comment: Te recomiendo que expliques el problema completo. El uso de cursores no es recomendado para la manipulación de datos porque su ejecución es lenta y lineal.